# Getting data from a view to populate a select drop-down

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to implement a feature of a fancy drop-down select box. I am going to use the Chosen module to get the functionality I want for the select box. I have a view that lists the data that I want to populate the select box. All I need to do is render a plain old HTML select box with the fields and rows from this view.

How can I do this? Is there a style plugin or anything out there? I personally haven't found one after searching.

Comment: Which Drupal version ?

Comment: Drupal 7 please : )

Comment: And you want to show this where? In a block? As a views header? In a form built using form API? Have you considered creating a Views jump menu? If not it should be fairly straightforward to create a custom module that includes such a select box in a form, using views_get_views_result and the form API. Chosen actually adds support for itself to Form API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of argiepiano's excellent suggestions, this is what I came up with: a module that provides a block with the select box populated by the view.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info
 */
function my_module_block_info() {

  $blocks['my_module'] = array(
    'info' => t('Puts the values of My Taxonomy Term view into a select box')
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view
 */
function my_module_block_view( $delta ) {

  $view_name = 'my_taxonomy_term_view';
  $display_name = '';

  $content = '<select>';

  $results = views_get_view_result($view_name, $display_name);

  foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $content .= '<option value=\'' . $result->tid . '\'>' 
      . $result->taxonomy_term_data_name . '</option>';
  }

  $content .= '</select>';

  $block['content'] = $content;

  return $block;
}
```